# What does "this" refer to when used in primefaces components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an autoComplete component in my xhtml file:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{locationController.selectedLocation}"
        onblur="LocationEditor.AutoCompleteElementChanged('#{encryptedCategory}','#{encryptedAttribute}', this)"
        forceSelection="true"
        var="currentLocation" itemLabel="#{currentLocation.name}"
        itemValue="#{currentLocation}" converter="#{locationConverter}"
        queryDelay="400"
        completeMethod="#{locationController.autoCompleteLocation}"
        maxResults="10">
        <p:column>
            #{currentLocation.name}
        </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Where in my javascript file the AutoCompleteElementChanged has been defined like this:

```
AutoCompleteElementChanged: function(category, attribute, autoCompleteElement) {
    if (autoCompleteElement.value.length < 1)
        return;
    var value = autoCompleteElement.value;
    //do something
}
```

When I pass `this` to my javaScript method `AutoCompleteElementChanged`, then its value (`autoCompleteElement.value`) is whatever I give to `itemLabel` in the `p:autoComplete`. Say if I had `itemlLabel="#{currentLocation.id}"` then `autoCompleteElement.value` will be the id of the currentLocation. Right now since I have `itemlLabel="#{currentLocation.name}"`, the js function gives me the name of the currentLocation when I use `autoCompleteElement.value`.

My Question is what is `this` exactly? What is it referring to and how can I modify it so that instead of it getting the value of `itemLabel` it gets the value of `itemValue` or another attribute? Because what I need in my js function is the id of the currentLocation and not its name

PS: I tried passing `currentLocation.id` directly to my javascript function instead of `this`, but it seems onblur is called before currentLocation is set, so it gives me the wrong id

Comment: Just check the JSF-generated HTML output in webbrowser?

Comment: @BalusC When I inspect element and look at the generated HTML for the p:autocomplete, its an HTML input and the onblur="LocationEditor.AutoCompleteElementChanged('somevalue', 'somevalue', this)" and value="the value for currentLocation.Name"

Comment: So I assume its using the `itemLabel` on the component to generate the `value` on HTML input and there is no way I can change it so that it sets the `value` to `itemvalue` instead in the auto-generation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the javascript object of the `input` generated by the autocomplete component.

Having:

```
<p:autoComplete onblur="console.log(this)"></p:autoComplete>
```

Would log in the console:

```
<input id="j_idt26:j_idt34_input" 
       name="j_idt26:j_idt34_input"
       type="text"
       class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
       autocomplete="off" onblur="console.log(this);" 
       role="textbox" aria-disabled="false"
       aria-readonly="false">
```

That's why you are getting the text filled in the input.

---

In order to get the `id` rather than the filled value, you could use [`hinput`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js#L11) provided by PF JS object:

```
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="autoCompleteWV" 
                onblur="console.log(PF('autoCompleteWV').hinput.val())">
</p:autoComplete>
```

*Note: the converter should be implemented.*